# UI objects on same position for every resolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a problem i created a button and text which is display correct on android resolution but when i change the resolution to free aspect it change the position of button and text like this

[image]

I tick the button component `Image (Script)` preserve aspect and changing the anchors of both object like this
[image]

[image]

but nothing happen i want to display these two on same position where it is when changing any resolution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not use Free Aspect to test different resolutions. Free aspect isn't really a resolution and often you can see bugs that you will not ever see on real devices.

For your problem anyway you have what's called Anchors in each UI element. An anchor defines where you want to "attach" your UI element and especially to what element or corner of the screen you want to attach it. For your example, on the Rect Transform, click on the square drawing (representing the anchors) and choose Bottom Left. 
[image]

Your element will be moved, you can move it where you want to and it will always be attached to the bottom left corner of your screen:

[image]

If you want to know more about UI for multiple resolutions, you can go here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Good luck!